# Return the count on each nested loop

Tags: javascript, string, loops, output

i am trying to see what i am doing wrong here?

so i am trying to build a function, that counts each element represented in three different strings:  the following, simon, ander and mads.  I get an incorrect answer in my output however:

```
3 6 100
3 3 100
```

The first two: is 3 and 6, that's correct, however the last one is 100 which i don't understand: it should be 5, since const mads has 5 elements in the input. Same with the 100 below, it should be 3, since all users have equal amount of elements.

```js
const simon = 'A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C';
const anders = 'B, A, B, C, B, A, B, C, B, A, B, C';
const mads = 'C, C, A, A, B, B, C, C, A, A, B, B';

function eksamen(svar) {
    let simonpoint = 0;
    let anderspoint = 0;
    let madspoint = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < svar.length; i++) {
        for(let s = 0; s < simon.length; s++) {
            if (svar[i] === simon[s]) {
                simonpoint++
            }
            for(let a = 0; a < anders.length; a++) {
                if (svar[i][s] === anders[a]) {
                    anderspoint++
                }
                    for(let m = 0; m < mads.length; m++) {
                        if (svar[i][a] === mads[m]) {
                            madspoint++
                    }
                } 
            }
        } return simonpoint + " " + anderspoint + " " + madspoint
    }  
} 
console.log(eksamen('BAACC'))
console.log(eksamen('AAAABBBBB'))
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the `svar` argument to the function? If you are just counting how many times a character appears in the 3 arrays, why pass anything to the function?

Comment: "svar" means "answer" i danish, so if the answer[i] === simon[s]

Comment: You are likely counting matches of `undefined`. `svar` is a string (like `BAACC`), and `svar[i]` gives you another string, which contains a single character. And then you try to apply a second index, which will give you `undefined`, unless it's `0`. Try these in the JavaScript console: `"abcd"[0]`, `"abcd"[1]`, `"abcd"[0][0]`, `"abcd"[1][0]`, `"abcd"[0][1]`, `"abcd"[1][1]`. So your checks with two indices do not work properly most of the time. Another thing is that the constants contain spaces and commas, which you will try to use in your loops when checking each character inside.

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you are trying to count? As tevemadar noted I don't think your nested loops are doing what you think they are.

Comment: Could you please add some extra context of the problem you are trying to solve? Its hard to understand.

Comment: Btw, just like the other comments, I don't understand the scoring either. If I forget the spaces and commas and compare the characters in `BAACC` to `ABCABCABC` (Simon's), there is not a single match between the character-pairs (besides that the first string is longer than the second one).

Comment: I am trying to implement a sort of multiple choice tester: we have three people who have 3 different answers, a,b,c: and i want to count who got the most point out of the answers.

Comment: then why not create a function that just looks for the number of matches of one person, and call that function with different arguments?

Comment: You shouldn't nest the for loops. For every letter in Simon's answer, you loop through _all_ letters in Anders' answer, and for every letter in Anders' answer, you loop through _all_ of Mads' letters. So Mads is looping simon.length^anders.length^mads.length times. Remove all if statements, and you will notice this yourself when you check how many times Mads have increased compared to Simon and Anders.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start of with saying that I probably didn't get your algorithm correct, as you mentioned that you feel the results for *simon* and *anders* are correct, but I get different results. That could be purely my misunderstanding.

I go with the assumptions that:

- Exam answers are ordered
- Student answers are ordered
- Therefor, each index of the student answer and the exam answer must match before a point is awarded
- More student answers than answers in the exam don't matter and vice versa

So taken from there, you can just write a function that normalizes the input to match with the exam questions, ie:

```
// flatten answers of the students as they seem to have a different pattern
const joined = studentAnswers.split(', ').join('');
```

Will normalize the string given by a student, say *simon* to `ABCABCABC`

To ensure, you don't overrun either of the arrays, we need to get the lowest bounds for the array

```
const maxLength = Math.min( answers.length, studentAnswers.length);
```

which ensures, if there were 10 answers given by the student, but only 5 answers available for the exam, we will only check the first 5 entries, at which time we just verify if the answer given by *simon* is exactly the same one the exam gives

```
for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
  // when the student gives the same answer as the exam, it's a point
  if (answers.charAt(i) === joined.charAt(i)) {
    result++;
  }
}
```

Now, since we want to do this for multiple students at once, we need a way to easily iterate the students and preferably make it reusable from that end, so we can use a function like:

```
function verifyExam( examAnswers, studentDict ) {
  return Object.entries( studentDict )
    .reduce( 
      (agg, [name, answers]) => `${agg} ${name} ${getResults( examAnswers, answers)}`, '');
}
```

Which takes an exam to verify, and a object with `{ studentName: answers, ... }`, so we build up the student object

```
const studentDict = { simon, anders, mads };
```

And we can then call the `verifyExam` function with the exam answers and the students attached to it

```js
const simon = 'A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C';
const anders = 'B, A, B, C, B, A, B, C, B, A, B, C';
const mads = 'C, C, A, A, B, B, C, C, A, A, B, B';

const examAnswers1 = 'BAACC';
const examAnswers2 = 'AAAABBBBB';

function getResults( answers, studentAnswers ) {
  // flatten answers of the students as they seem to have a different pattern
  const joined = studentAnswers.split(', ').join('');
  // get the maximum numbers of answers to check
  const maxLength = Math.min( answers.length, studentAnswers.length);
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    // when the student gives the same answer as the exam, it's a point
    if (answers.charAt(i) === joined.charAt(i)) {
      result++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function verifyExam( examAnswers, studentDict ) {
  return Object.entries( studentDict )
    .reduce( 
      (agg, [name, answers]) => `${agg} ${name} ${getResults( examAnswers, answers)}`, '');
}

const studentDict = { simon, anders, mads };

console.log( examAnswers1, verifyExam( examAnswers1, studentDict ) );
console.log( examAnswers2, verifyExam( examAnswers2, studentDict ) );
```